# Proving there are infinite primes of some form $a+nd$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

I know by [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) that there are infinitely many primes of any type $a+nd$, where $a$ and $d$ are positive co-prime integers.

I come across many questions like - prove that there are infinitely many primes of form $4k+1, 6k+1, 6k+5, 8k+1,$ etc. where they use either quaratic residues or take some form of a number formed by the finite (assumed) set of primes of that form and then reach a contradiction.

I want to know how to tackle any such problem requiring to prove it for a certain form, it seems very non-trivial to me to begin.

Comment: There are informative answers at [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16735/is-a-non-analytic-proof-of-dirichlets-theorem-on-primes-known-or-possible).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't want the proof of Dirichlet's theorem, I want how should we go about proving it for a certain form like $7k+3$ for eg.

Comment: You can use the "Euclidean proof" as in $4k+1$ etc. , if and only if Murty's criterion is met, see my answer. So the answer is, that you must use more analytic arguments involving $L$-series for cases like $7k+3$. Of course, all cases follow from Dirichlet's Theorem anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Euclidean proof, as for $4k+1,6k+1,6k+5,8k+1$ etc. is not always possible. In fact, we have the following Theorem:

*Theorem 1*. (Murty) A “Euclidean proof” exists for the arithmetic progression
$l \bmod k$ if and only if $l^2 \equiv 1 \bmod k$.

Proof: See [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.225.9834&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the added reference

Comment: The introduction of this references discusses exactly what you have asked, if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes, that was very specific to my query

Comment: Very good :) :)