# Prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $25m+7$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Suppose there are only finitely many primes of the form $25m+7$. 
Let $p_1,\ldots, p_r$ be such primes and let $M = (5p_1\ldots p_r)^2 + 7$. Then $N$ has form $25m + 7$, and is not divisible by any $p_i$. Let $p$ be any prime dividing $M$. Then $(5p_1\ldots p_r)^2 \equiv -7 \mod{p}$,
but this means that the number $−7$ is a square$\mod p$,which is only possible if $p \equiv 7 \mod 25$.
This contradicts the fact that no $p_i$ divides $M$. Therefore there must be infinitely of that form.

Does this prove my claim? I was following a layout of a proof for primes of the from $4n+1$, and tried to modify it.

Update: the claim that $-7$ is a square $\mod p$,whenever $p\equiv 7 \mod 25$ does not hold so some other claim is needed

Comment: "which is only possible if $p\equiv 7 \pmod{25}$" -- why is this true?

Comment: e.g. $2^2\equiv -7\pmod{11}$, but $11$ is not congruent to $7$, modulo $25$.

Comment: $-7$ is a square modulo $11$.

Comment: Actually, I mentioned that I was following a layout of another proof - so I am not sure about the answer

Comment: Of course this follows from [Diriclet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).  Is there any reason to think this is substantially easier than the general case?

Comment: @lulu I see it follows from that theorem but I would like to have a proof of it

Comment: Of course there may be a clever trick that works for this case, but at some point surely it is easier to just understand the proof of Dirichlet's Theorem.

Comment: @lulu But I want to find the trick .. maybe if i consider the product ofprimes or smth..

Comment: Well, again, it isn't clear to me that there even is a sensible trick.  I mean, something significantly easier than the proof of Dirichlet.  If you want to press further on it, I'd start by trying to show that there are infinitely many primes of the form $5n+2$.  Your desired claim is stronger than that, of course.

Comment: @Lulu I think i can show that, but I don't know how to relate it to my exercise

Comment: Again, it would be a major step towards what you want.  If a given problem is too hard it is a very good idea to weaken the question slightly and see if you can prove that.  Standard practice.  To me, the $5n+2$ case already looks hard. Just saying "I want to find a trick" isn't a sensible way to proceed.

Comment: I think lulu is right; one should use Dirichlet's theorem, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2505667/proving-there-are-infinite-primes-of-some-form-and).

Answer (score 1):

The logical structure of your proof is fine, but there is one huge claim that you have stated without proof:

> the number $−7$ is a square$\mod p$, which is only possible if $p \equiv 7 \mod 25$.

This claim is in fact not true.  For instance, $-7$ is a square mod $2$, or mod $11$, even though $2$ and $11$ are not $7$ mod $25$.  More generally, by quadratic reciprocity, if $p\neq 2,7$ is a prime, then $-7$ is a square mod $p$ iff $p$ is a square mod $7$; that is, iff $p$ is $1,2,$ or $4$ mod $7$.

Comment: I understand. I followed another proof and I see it does not makes sense. Do you have any idea how to fix this?