# infinitude of primes of special form

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

Any number prime can only be written as $10k + x$ for $x=1,3,7,9$ since others cannot be primes.
Is there a way to prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $10k+3$ or $10k+7$?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691165/prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-25m7).

Comment: It follows again from Dirichlet's theorem, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2505667/proving-there-are-infinite-primes-of-some-form-and).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know the theorem but I wanted a proof. Thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Let $F$ be a finite set of primes of the form $10k+3$ or $10k+7$. Let $P$ be the product of the elements of $F\setminus\{3\}$ (which is simply $F$ if $3\notin F$) and let $N=10P+3$. Note that $N$ is even and that $5\nmid N$. On the other hand, not all prime factors of $N$ are of the type $10k+1$ or $10k+9$, because the product of several numbers of this type is again of this type. Therefore, $N$ has a prime factor $p$ which is of one the forms $10k+3$ and $10k+7$. Furthermore, $p\neq3$, because$$3\mid N\iff3\mid10P\iff3\mid P,$$which is impossible, since $P$ is a product of prime numbers, none of which is $3$.

So, $N$ has a prime factor $p$ which is of the form $10k+3$ (but distinct from $3$) or of the form $10k+7$. But then $p\notin F$, because\begin{align}p\in F\iff&p\in F\setminus\{3\}\\\implies&p\mid P\\\implies&p\mid10P\\\implies&p\mid3\text{ (because $3=N-10P$)}\\\implies&p=3,\end{align}which is false.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I looked more closely, and I cannot follow why $p  |  P \Rightarrow p 
 | 5$?  Is it because it divides $N$?

Comment: @mandella Yes. Since $p\mid N$ and $p\mid10P$ (because $p\mid P$), $p\mid(N-10P)$, which means that $p\mid5$.

Comment: And also, $p \notin F$ follows because if $p | 5 $ then $p$ is either $5$ or $1$, neither of which can be in the set, correct?

Comment: @mandella Almost. The only possibility is $p=5$, since I assumed that $p$ is prime. But $5\notin F$.

Comment: Yes I forgot that it was supposed to be a prime and $5$ does not have the form $10k+3$ or $10k+7$

Comment: Why couldn't $N$ be a power of $5$?

Comment: @Wojowu I suppose it *can* be a power of $5$. And... ?

Comment: @Wojowu Actually, I've just proved that it *can't* be a power of $5$. The relevance of this still eludes me, though.

Comment: You claim that $N$ has a prime factor of the form $10k+3$ or $10k+7$. However, I don't think this conclusion holds - $N$ may only have prime factors $10k+1,10k+9$ and $5$.

Comment: @Wojowu You are right. I shall edit my answer, but I can't do it right now.

Comment: @Wojowu what happens in that case? I thought it wasn't in the set at all

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos could you explain what happens in this case bc I have a quiz tomorrow and would like to know this

Comment: @mandella Done!

Comment: Could you explain why since $5$ is not the only prime factor, it follows that $N$ can not have prime factors of the form $10k + 1$ or $10k + 9$?

Comment: @mandella No, I cannot. I never claimed that. All I wrote was that, since $5$ is not the only prime factor, then $N$ must have a prime factor of the form  $10k+3$ or of the form $10k+7$.

Comment: But it cannot have all of them of that form right?

Comment: @mandella Of course not. $5$ must be a prime factor too.

Comment: Also another question. If we take $\frac{N}{5}$ why can't it have prime factors only of the form $10n+1$ and $10n+9$? @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @mandella Why? Suppose that $F=\{3,7,13,17\}$. Then $N=46\,415$ and one of its prime factors is $9\,283$.

Comment: Yes but then this implies that our number can have such factors, so doesn't need to have prime factors $10k+3$ or $10k+7$

Comment: @mandella Didn't you notice that $9\,283$ **is** of the form $10k+3$?

Comment: I do not see why $\frac{N}{5}$ cannot have ONLY prime factors $10k+1$ or $10k+9$ ... @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @mandella I made a mistake and I will correct it within less than a hour.

Comment: @mandella Done. I believe that it is correct now, but if it isn't, then please unmark my answer as the accepted on, so that I can delete it. And please excuse me for wasting your time.

Comment: No, thank you for your time! I believe it is correct as well now.

Answer (score 2):

This comes from Dirichlet's theorem, but there is an elementary way to
prove that the set
$$A=\{n\in\Bbb N:n\equiv\pm3\pmod{10}\}$$
contains infinitely many primes. Prove that each number of the form
$$10N+3$$
has a prime factor $p$ in the set $A$. Now take $N$ to be the product
of some primes in $A$ but excluding $3$. Then $p$ will be a further
prime ($\ne 3$) in $A$.